# Dependency managment in maven

Tags: maven, spring-cloud, dependency-management

Can someone explain me why my parent POM doesn't provide versions of dependecies for my child projects? I read 10 times docs on maven site and I'm stuck.

Here's my parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <dockerfile-version>1.4.13</dockerfile-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <modules>
        <module>credit</module>
        <module>customer</module>
        <module>product</module>
        <module>netflix-eureka-naming-server</module>
        <module>APIGateway</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
       ...
    </build>
</project>
```

and one POM of my service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.taradaszje</groupId>
    <artifactId>APIGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>APIGateway</name>
    <description>API Gateway for API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
     ...
    </build>
</project>
```

in this example version for API gateway isn't provide. In my opinion Hoxton.RELEASE should set the 2.2.1 version.

Another curious thing 
[image]

Comment: Sorry, which  dependency are we talking about?

Comment: In child POM i want to add version provided in parent POM( in this case hoxton.RELEASE version)  to spring-cloud-starter-gateway .

Comment: The `spring-cloud-dependencies` is a BOM of BOMs. Are you sure the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` is defined somewhere in there?

Comment: spring-cloud-dependecies -> spring-cloud-gateway-dependecies -> spring-cloud-starter-gateway I am sure.

Comment: your child pom doesn't have your parent as the parent.

Comment: You have right @spencergibb. I try to resolve this on my own now.

Comment: @spencergibb I know that You are developer at Pivotal so let's make it clear. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__quick_start.html in section 1.1 there is example how to do it but if I have a lot of services using the same dependency, this solution isn't the best choice( need to make changes in every service). So can you give me advice or show helpfull article about it, I will be thankfull.

Comment: You are using the same groupId/artifactId/version as spring-boot does? And trying to define modules like `credit` etc. in in this pom ? That simply will not work cause a groupId/artifactId/version is unique and can't be used by anyone else neither should that be done. Your parent should have different coordinates (usually of your company or your project)..never try reuse coordinates of existing artifacts which is causing this issues...

Comment: Nevermind. I just change parent pom coordinates to some unique and  provided relativePath to my parent pom. That's all. Thanks everyone for help !